# Self bound generic type with fluent interface and inheritance

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, fluent-interface

I am using a fluent interface with inheritance. I declared the base class Constructor protected so you cant create a Foo<Bar> which would result in a ClassCastException on calling add(). But i am having trouble with the static method that returns a new Foo instance.

```
public class Foo<T extends Foo<T>> // if i change to extends Foo i only get warnings
{
        public static Foo<Foo> createFoo() // <-- error
        {
                return new Foo<Foo>(); // <-- error
        }

        protected Foo() {}

        public T add()
        {
                //...
                return (T)this;
        }
}

public class Bar extends Foo<Bar>
{
        public Bar sub()
        {
                //...
                return this;
        }
}
```

This is mostly an excercise(personal not homework) in Fluent Interfaces, Domain-specific language and Generics, so please dont ask what i need it for.

Edit: Eclipse error

```
Bound mismatch: The type Foo is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Foo<T>> of the type Foo<T>
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354740/is-there-a-way-to-refer-to-the-current-type-with-a-type-variable/7355094#7355094) should help explain the meaning of the error you're seeing (after the bold EDIT specifically). In the future please post the complete error message in your question.

Comment: I dont know what the downvote is for, i searched for selfbound generic types on google and could not find an answer to my problem.

Comment: @Stefan Agreed, totally valid question. Upvoted to counter.

Comment: The answer linked actually helped me solve the problem. Change Foo declaration to: public abstract class AbstractFoo<T extends AbstractFoo<T>>. Create final class ConcreteFoo extends AbstractFoo<ConcreteFoo> without extra functionality. It does however destroy some of the inheritance.

Comment: Generics can really be a pain if you "misuse" (no offense) them like this. I am really a friend of them, but sometimes they make it much harder to write code as without them. Try to declare different types instead of a recursive structure, which is hard to maintain and extend.

Comment: @Stephan I agree. At this point im trying to see how far i can take the language. Especially since i like the idea of fluent interfaces in combination with the Builder pattern.

Comment: @Stefan - Glad my linked answer helped, seems it was more relevant than I thought. I used the fluent/builder combination for a home-rolled query builder API, and this little trick was the key to supporting a call like `RedQueryBuilder = new RedQueryBuilder().baseMethod().redMethod();`. It's just important to realize that it isn't suited to be publicly extendable since there's nothing forcing an extending class to follow the rules. For example, one can declare `class EvilQueryBuilder extends QueryBuilder<AnotherQueryBuilder>`.

Comment: @Kublai Khan coincidentally im using it for a personal 'query builder API' ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You essentially have a recursive type declaration.

`Foo<T extends Foo<T>>`.

So let's say you have a `Foo<Foo>`.  That means `T` is mapped to `Foo`.  But `Foo` is not subtype of `Foo<T>`, which in this case is `Foo<Foo>`, so what you're really looking for is `Foo<Foo<Foo>>`.  But wait a minute, the innermost `Foo` isn't typed, so I guess it's `Foo<Foo<Foo<Foo>>>`...oh forget it!

To put a more understandable face on it, consider if you had `Foo<T extends List<T>>`.  What could you possibly use for `T` in a declaration/instantiation of `Foo`?  `List<String>`?  `List<List>`?

### Edit

It looks like you found a way to "break" the recursion cycle.  You eventually need to get to a reified type.  In the same way that you found that `ConcreteFoo` worked for you, you could similarly for the `List` example above have some class `ConreteListOfItself implements List<ConreteListOfItself>` that would break the recursion cycle.

Comment: I guess the problem stems from the fact that Foo doesnt extend itself.

Comment: @Stefan: Well, `extends` in the context of a type bound means a subclass **or** the class itself.  So the problem isn't that `Foo` doesn't extend `Foo`, the problem is that `Foo` doesn't extend `Foo<Foo>`.  Just like `List` doesn't extend `List<List>`, but some subclass could.

Comment: I am going to accept this answer, as it explains why what im trying to do 'doesnt' work. At this point i think i need a more powerful Generics mechanism in line of what Kublai Khan says [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354740/is-there-a-way-to-refer-to-the-current-type-with-a-type-variable/7355094#7355094) in order to get working fluent interfaces with inheritance structure.