# In Java, how do I make instance variables of a subclass have the type of the subclass, rather than of the superclass?

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I'm writing a HuffmanTree class for a Java project that inherits from a BinaryNode class.  I want to work with HuffmanTree nodes instead of BinaryNode nodes.  BinaryNode has left and right instance variables of type BinaryNode, and I want HuffmanTree to have the same instance variables (i.e. left and right), but of type HuffmanTree instead.

How would I go about doing this?  Thanks!

EDIT:  Here's some of the BinaryNode code:

```
public class BinaryNode<T> implements BinaryNodeInterface<T>, 
                               java.io.Serializable
{
//The BinaryNode's instance variables were changed to protected so we can access them
//from the HuffmanTree class.
private T data;
private BinaryNode<T> left;
private BinaryNode<T> right;

public BinaryNode()
{
    this(null); // call next constructor
} // end default constructor

public BinaryNode(T dataPortion)
{
    this(dataPortion, null, null); // call next constructor
} // end constructor

public BinaryNode(T dataPortion, BinaryNode<T> leftChild,
                               BinaryNode<T> rightChild)
{
    data = dataPortion;
    left = leftChild;
    right = rightChild;
} // end constructor
```

Comment: Probably through generics.

Comment: What does the BinaryNode code look like?

Comment: Please share some piece of code.

Comment: Generics may not work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959335/self-bound-generic-type-with-fluent-interface-and-inheritance

Comment: Okay I added some of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing from the names of the classes and interfaces, the first step would be to change the declaration of left and right to

```
protected BinaryNodeInterface<T> left;
protected BinaryNodeInterface<T> right;
```

Then your `BinaryNode` constructor can be

```
public BinaryNode(T dataPortion, BinaryNode<T> leftChild,
                           BinaryNode<T> rightChild)
{
    data = dataPortion;
    left = leftChild;
    right = rightChild;
} // end constructor
```

and your `HuffmanTree` constructor can be

```
public HuffmanTree(T dataPortion, HuffmanTree<T> leftChild,
                           HuffmanTree<T> rightChild)
{
    data = dataPortion;
    left = leftChild;
    right = rightChild;
} // end constructor
```

And all should work.  You can even change the `BinaryNode` constructor to

```
public BinaryNode(T dataPortion, BinaryNodeInterface<T> leftChild,
                           BinaryNodeInterface<T> rightChild)
{
    data = dataPortion;
    left = leftChild;
    right = rightChild;
} // end constructor
```

That would probably do the trick too, with no code duplication.

Note that once you do this, any existing code that assumes that `left` and `right` are instances of `BinaryNode<T>` will have to be updated.  The best thing to do is to change the code to rely only on `BinaryNodeInterface<T>`, but that's not always possible.

Inside `BinaryNode` methods, it should be safe (depending on your methods' contract) to simply cast: `BinaryNode<T> node = (BinaryNode<T>) left;`.  In `HuffmanTree` methods, it might not be safe to call `HuffmanTree<T> node = (HuffmanTree<T>) left`, since `left` might be a `BinaryNode` without being a `HuffmanTree`.  You'll have to work out the logic in these cases yourself.

Comment: Changing the declaration of left and right to protected and declaring using BinaryNoteInterface<T> gave me a bunch of errors saying I can't convert BinaryNodeInterface<T> to BinaryNode<T>.

Comment: If I do that it screws up pretty much all of my other methods though.  EDIT:  Never mind I got it fixed.  Thanks!

Comment: Definitely the casting.  That was a pain to do but it's working now.

Comment: Updated answer accordingly