# Java defining covariant return from superclass

Tags: java, generics, covariance

I have the following abstract class:

```
public abstract class AbstractSharpCollection<T> implements SharpCollection<T>
```

and an interface

```
public interface SharpCollection<T> extends Iterable<T>
{
    SharpCollection<T> tail();
}
```

There's a lot of other methods defined in SharpCollection, which return another SharpCollection. The logic of all those methods rely only on the iterator.

I want to be able to create a method on AbstractSharpCollection, such that the call to tail() would return the instance of the subclass, and not the superclass.

Something like

```
public <V extends SharpCollection<T>> V tail() { //code logic here }
```

I know that I can override the return type on the subclasses that extend the AbstractSharpCollection, but having to override all the methods only to change the return type is really ugly, troublesome, and prone to errors.

Is there any way at all that I can achieve what I want?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Implementing `tail` would be quite difficult. `null` is the only valid return value.

It appears you need to parameterise the `SharpCollection` so that it "knows" the actual interface type being used:

```
public interface SharpCollection<
    THIS extends SharpCollection<THIS, T>,
    T
> extends Iterable<T> {
    THIS tail();
}
```

Unfortunately this complicates the client code as well.

Comment: hi, can you please ellaborate on your solution, din't quiet get it. or provide a help link to it. :) thanks.

Comment: Actually, I'm using this solution to solve the tail problem, but it doesn't solve all the cases, and subclasses have to declare two parameter types, when it should be only one.

Comment: @Aman See my answer here for more details on implementing this pattern: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7355094/697449