# Recursive generics in Java

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to implement a class representing an XML tree as follows:

```
    public class XML<T extends XML<T>> {

        private final List<MarkupLanguage> nodeList = new ArrayList<>();

        private final Map<String, String> attributeList = new HashMap<>();

        public T attr(final String key, final String value) {
            if (value != null) {
                this.attributeList.put(key, value);
            } 
            return (T) this;
        }

        public T appendTo(final T node) {
            node.add(this);
            return (T) this;
        }
        ...
    }
```

My problem is typing of these clauses - I am getting unchecked cast for "return (T) this;"

and also when I try to use the XML class by itself:

```
    final XML url = new XML("url");
    new XML("loc")
        .add("http://goout.cz")
        .appendTo(url);
```

I am getting:

```
    Unchecked cast to call appendTo(T) as a member of raw type XML.
```

How can I improve my code to get better typing?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `XML<T extends XML<T>>`?

Comment: @BheshGurung: probably as a "self type", to be able to for an instance to refer to its own type

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354740/is-there-a-way-to-refer-to-the-current-type-with-a-type-variable/7355094#7355094

Comment: Paul Bellora: This is exactly answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about the approach below (simple inheritance plus generic methods):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;

public class XmlTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        XMLFirstSubclass url = new XMLFirstSubclass("url");
        XMLSecondSubclass xmlSecondSubclassInstance = new XMLSecondSubclass(
                "loc").add("http://goout.cz").appendTo(url);
    }
}

abstract class XML {

    private final List<String> texts = new ArrayList<String>();

    private final List<XML> nodes = new ArrayList<XML>();

    private final String nodeName;

    protected XML(String nodeName) {
        this.nodeName = nodeName;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <R extends XML> R add(String text) {
        texts.add(text);
        return (R) this;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <R extends XML, T extends XML> R add(T node) {
        nodes.add(node);
        return (R) this;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <R extends XML, T extends XML> R appendTo(T node) {
        node.add(this);
        return (R) this;
    }
}

class XMLFirstSubclass extends XML {
    public XMLFirstSubclass(String nodeName) {
        super(nodeName);
    }
}

class XMLSecondSubclass extends XML {
    public XMLSecondSubclass(String nodeName) {
        super(nodeName);
    }
}
```

Note that the generic methods allow to get a node from one type T and return the instance's type R, which can be different than the argument's type. T can be different than R, but both inherit XML.

**Comments about the approach presented in the question**

The approach that you're using until now can lead to strange situtations. 
Let's illustrate this with an example.

Below, we try to write the first class that specializes XML:

```
public class XMLFirstSubclass extends XML<OtherXMLSubclass> { ... }
```

If we're writing the first XML subclass, the only possible values to OtherXMLSubclass is XMLFirstSubclass or not declaring the generic type at all.

First option:

```
public class XMLFirstSubclass extends XML<XMLFirstSubclass> { ... }
```

Second:

```
public class XMLFirstSubclass extends XML { ... }
```

If you chose to use generics in your class design, the second option seems bad.
Taking a closer look into the first option, it opens the possibility of getting subclasses like:

```
class XMLSecondSubclass extends XML<XMLFirstSubclass> {
    ... 
}
```

Note that this compiles perfectly, but will cause class cast exceptions in XMLSecondSubclass method calls at runtime.

Comment: umm... what about `public class XMLFirstSubclass extends XML<XMLFirstSubclass>`?

Answer (score 5):

Just type it:

```
final XML<T> url = new XML<T>("url");
new XML<T>("loc")
    .add("http://goout.cz")
    .appendTo(url);
```

It also looks like you really want to use `XML<T>` for your methods, not `T`, so you can avoid the casts (but I could be wrong):

```
public XML<T> attr(String key, String value) {
    if (value != null) {
        this.attributeList.put(key, value);
    } 
    return this;
}

public XML<T> appendTo(XML<T> node) {
    node.add(this);
    return this;
}
```

Comment: I think he wants to do something like `class XMLSubclass extends XML<SMLSubclass>` and then be able to do `XMLSubclass foo = new XMLSubclass("loc").add("http://goout.cz").appendTo(url);` He wouldn't be able to do this with your method.

Comment: Yes, he is wanting the return type to be of the subclass for the methods. This example isn't very good at showing what his intentions of the return type is.

Comment: I really need to have `public T appendTo` as when I inherit for instance `class HTML extends XML<HTML>`, I need to have a return type `HTML`.