# Java (Processing 1.5.1): Fluent interface @ multilevel inheritance via generics

Tags: java, generics, processing, fluent-interface, method-chaining

I try to implement a **fluent interface** in my 2D game engine.

Simplified example of my implementation:

```
public class Sprite<T> {

    protected float x = 0.0;
    protected float y = 0.0;

    public T setPosition(float x, float y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        return (T)this;
    }

}

public class Living<T extends Living> extends Sprite<Living> {

    protected boolean alive = false;

    public T setAlive(boolean alive) {
        this.alive = alive;
        return (T)this;
    }

}

public class Entity<T extends Entity> extends Living<Entity> {

    protected String name = null;

    public T setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return (T)this;
    }

}


Entity entity = new Entity().setPosition(100, 200).setAlive(true).setName("Zombie");
```

I keep getting the error: **"The function setAlive(boolean) does not exist."**

I know, using my methods the other way round (in a more logical order) works:

```
Entity entity = new Entity().setName("Zombie").setAlive(true).setPosition(100, 200);
```

And I know that overwriting any parent setter functions in each and every child class would work:

```
public class Entity extends Living {

    protected String name = null;

    public Entity setPosition(float x, float y) {
        return (Entity)super.setPosition(x, y);
    }

    public Entity setAlive(boolean alive) {
        return (Entity)super.setAlive(alive);
    }

    public Entity setName(String name) {
        return (Entity)super.setName(name);
    }

}
```

But I want the **interface** to be as **free/uncomplicated** as possible for the 'end user' and the **code** to be as **compact and clean as it gets**.

I don't know if I just messed up the generics or my hole approach is completely wrong. I hope you can help. I am open to any advice. *(Sorry for my bad english.)*

**Edit:**
I already tested the following approach and **it works for the Entity class**.

```
public class Sprite<T> {
...
}

public class Living<T> extends Sprite<T> {
...
}

public class Entity extends Living<Entity> {
...
}
```

I forgot to mention, that I need to instantiate Sprite & Living too. For example:

```
Living living = new Living().setPosition(50, 50).setAlive(false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your class model is over complicated, you can pass generic parameter down to the child class and then declare it explicitly:

```
public class Sprite<T> {
...
}

public class Living<T> extends Sprite<T> {
...
}

public class Entity extends Living<Entity> {
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. **Works for Entity**. But I should have mentioned that I also **need to instantiate Sprite & Living**.
If I implement your approach I get the same error as above while instantiating Living like this:
`Living living = new Living().setPosition(50, 50).setAlive(false);`

Comment: you can do `new Living<Living>();`

Comment: If I test this:
`Living living = new Living<Living>().setPosition(100, 200).setAlive(true);`
I get: **"cannot convert from Object to Living"**

Comment: I think you need to have a separate class for concrete Living type, like `ConcreteLiving extends Living<Living>` for every type you are going to instantiate

Comment: Not what I wanted to hear, but certainly the right answer. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a valiant attempt at the [curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) in Java. The problem is that you're mixing generics and raw types which means you aren't "closing the loop" of the pattern. For example your declaration of `Living`:

```
public class Living<T extends Living> extends Sprite<Living>
```

Should really be:

```
public class Living<T extends Living<T>> extends Sprite<T>
```

At some point you'll need to declare a "leaf" class that resolves `T`, otherwise you won't be able to instantiate and declare variables of these types without resorting to raw types or wildcards (which defeats the purpose of the pattern). For example:

```
public final class ConcreteEntity extends Entity<ConcreteEntity>
```

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354740/is-there-a-way-to-refer-to-the-current-type-with-a-type-variable/7355094#7355094) for more details on implementing this pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already tried this approach. But a forgot to mention that I also **need to instantiate Sprite & Living**.

Comment: That won't be possible. You'll need to create an inheritance tree in which only the leaves are instantiable. That should be trivial to do though. It's what I wound up doing in the solution I mentioned in my linked answer - where normally I would've used a base class directly, instead I made a trivial offshoot class in order to resolve the recursive type parameter.

Comment: Seems like I have to add some more classes then. Thank you very much. :)