# Java avoid class cast warning in hierarchical Builder pattern

Tags: java, generics

Is there a way to avoid the unchecked class cast in this hierarchical Builder pattern?

```
public abstract class BaseBuilder <T, B extends BaseBuilder<T,B>> {

  public B setB1(String b1) {
    this.b1 = b1;
    return (B) this; // can I make this unchecked cast go away?
  }

  abstract public T build();

  String b1;
}
```

and no, the answer is not:

```
return B.class.cast(this);
```

and yes, I know I could use @SuppressWarnings

Comment: Unfortunately, Java doesn't allow for enforcing B to be the "current" class, and the unchecked warning is there to remind you that. `class MBB1<String, MBB2>`, `class MBB2<String, MBB2>`, what do you expect `MBB1.setB1()` to do?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354740/is-there-a-way-to-refer-to-the-current-type-with-a-type-variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said before, this can't be done, because it is not safe. `B` extends `BaseBuilder<T,B>`, but `BaseBuilder<T,B>` (type of `this`) does not extend `B`. Recursive bounds are almost NEVER useful in Java, and do not give you the self-type. You should get rid of it.

You can add an abstract method such that implementing classes must give an instance of `B`:

```
public abstract class BaseBuilder <T, B> {

  abstract public B getB();

  public B setB1(String b1) {
    this.b1 = b1;
    return getB();
  }

  abstract public T build();

  String b1;
}
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of the shenanigans like: `public class EvilBuilder extends BaseBuilder<Thing1, Thing1Builder> {...`

Answer (score 2):

Yes; return `BaseBuilder<T, B>` and force subclasses to override `setB1` to return themselves.

Comment: @Saintali: they don't have to return themselves. They just have to return an instance of `B`. So all you need is to have a return type of `B`.

Answer (score 1):

besides of what louis said the following is a somewhat nice design:

```
public abstract class BaseBuilder ... {
    ...
    public B setB1(String b1) {
        this.b1 = b1;
        return self();
    }

    abstract protected B self();
    ...
}

public class SomeBuilder extends BaseBuilder ... {
    @override
    protected SomeBuilder self() {
        return this;
    }
}
```