# Convenient way to write generic interface that points out to its implementor

Tags: java, generics

Is there in java a way to write generic interface what points out to the implementor of such interface in more convenient way?

For example I've write interface:

```
public interface Updatable<T> {
    void updateData(T t);
}
```

I want to point out that only instance of implementor can be passed in updateData(T t) method.

So, i have to write something like this:

```
public class Office implements Updatable<Office> {

@Override
    public void updateData(Office office) {
        //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
...
...
...
}
```

But seems it is a little ugly. Do you have better variants?

Comment: That's how `Comparable<?>` does it. Why shouldn't you?

Comment: Yep, Comparable does it as I've pointed out in my example. But I want better way if possible.

Comment: I don't see the problem. This is the purpose of Generics, to specify a type. And that is what you're doing. It's not ugly. Check out [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-genericdao/index.html) and how they are using Generics for a DAO.

Comment: Related: [Is there a way to refer to the current type with a type variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354740/is-there-a-way-to-refer-to-the-current-type-with-a-type-variable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People have been asking for the "This" type, mostly for fluent APIs. It's probably never gonna make it. But I think it's ok to just establish a convention - name the type variable `This` to represent the type of `this`. So readers see `This` and know exactly what it is supposed to be; misuse is unlikely

```
public interface Updatable<This> {
    void updateData(This t);
}

// any Foo implementing Updatable must supply This=Foo

public class Office implements Updatable<Office>
```

Since `This` must be a subtype of `Updatable<This>`, people often express that constraint

```
public interface Updatable<This extends Updatable<This>>
```

I think it is not necessary, and should not be done. The naming convention of `This` is good enough.

That constraint is not strict enough either to prevent misuse. For example

```
public interface Foo<T extends Foo<T>>

public class Foo1 implements Foo<Foo1>  // good, intended use

public class Foo2 implements Foo<Foo1>  // compiles! but not intended
```

Comment: Thanks, seems this answer is most approached to my question. Must accept.

Answer (score 3):

This is fine and is the least ugly way and clearest way to do it.

Generics is only there to ensure type safety, i.e. avoid casts. Your `Updatable` interface is perfectly type-safe already. So why change anything?

> I want to point out that only instance of implementor can be passed in
>   updateData(T t) method.

The key question is: *Why* do you want to do that? I don't see any type-safety reason from looking at the interface itself why this is needed.

If the `Office` class requires that the parameter to its `updateData` method be `Office`, fine. But that would be a requirement specific to the `Office` class, and thus `Office` should be responsible (and it is in your code) for implementing the interface with the appropriate type parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I would write

```
public interface Updatable<T extends Updatable<?>> {
    void updateData(T t);
}
```

No less ugly, but more explicit that `T` has to implement the interface.

Comment: A little explicit version. Thanks!

Comment: but there's no point in making this restriction from a type safety point of view