# java generics with ArrayList

Tags: java, generics

I have java Generics related question

I have Parents class called `Container` like below: Container can contain other containers and `Services`. Services class extends Container but can contain only `ServiceMembers` which also extend Container.

The below code doesnt work even though in the Services class I override the parents class's `getElements()` method and return an ArrayList of elements which are also Subclass of the Container class.

Any idea on how I can get this to work or I am just using it the wrong way ?

```
public class Container
{
   protected ArrayList<Container> elements = new ArrayList<Container>();

   public ArrayList<Container> getElements()
   {
   }
}

public class Service extends Container
{
  public ArrayList<ServiceMember> getElements()
  {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you simply need to modify the `Container` class like this:

```
public class Container<T extends Container> {
   protected List<T> elements = new ArrayList<T>();

   public List<T> getElements() {
       return elements;  
   }
}
```

This will allow you to parametrize it with all of the subclasses of the `Container` class (or itself).

The `Service` class would look like this:

```
public class Service extends Container<Service> {

}
```

At final, you can instantiate objects of these classes like this:

```
Service s = new Service();
ArrayList<Service> elements = s.getElements();

Container<Container> c = new Container<Container>();
ArrayList<Container> els = c.getElements();

//adding an element to each of the lists:
c.getElements().add(new Container<Container>());
System.out.println(c.getElements().size());

s.getElements().add(new Service());
System.out.println(s.getElements().size());
```

**Anyway, I would recommend you to think very carefully on the design, because mixing raw classes with generics is unsafe and confusing.**

Comment: Note that `Container` is a raw type in `T extends Container`.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response while I try the suggested solution.. was wondering if u were seeing a fundmental flaw in the way my objects are arranged.. can u advise .. thanks

Comment: also how to I add to the Elements list ? I tried your suggestions and I am able to return the type of list but i see issue adding elements

Comment: -1 Sorry, but mixing raw types with generics is confusing and potentially unsafe.

Comment: Ofcourse it is and that's why I recommended Chandu to consider very carefully his design snd the archtecture of classes.

Comment: +1 `extends Container<T>` won't work. Finally, a use case for `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")` :)

Comment: Thanks Everyone for helping me out and get a little more understanding of the generics. What Kocko suggested worked for me... and also for what Ravi suggested as an improvement for RAW

Comment: @Chandu I strongly recommend against using this solution. Its pitfalls are subtle and may only become apparent later on. See [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it). Kocko is recommending the "curiously recurring template pattern", but his solution "cheats" with raw types. Even when implemented correctly, this pattern is open to abuse and mistakes. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354740/is-there-a-way-to-refer-to-the-current-type-with-a-type-variable/7355094#7355094).

Comment: @Chandu As kocko mentioned, the true solution is to rethink your design here. I sense that some of these classes are playing multiple roles and it will help to try and decouple each responsibility into its own interface/class. Also, look at using composition instead of inheritance where possible, since inheritance is playing a role in your issue here. See [Difference between Inheritance and Composition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399544/difference-between-inheritance-and-composition) for more info on that concept.

Answer (score 1):

> The below code doesnt work even though in the Services class I override the parents class's getElements() method and return an ArrayList of elements which are also Subclass of the Container class.

This is not correct. Due to *type erasure* `ArrayList<ServiceMember>` is not consider a co-variant return required for overriding `getElements()` method.

Override as follows. You don't lose out on Polymorphism and it would still happen since it depends on the `Object`'s type (dynamic; at runtime) and not the type of its reference (static; at compile time).

```
public class Service extends Container
{
  public ArrayList<Container> getElements()
  {
    // declare superclass Container
    ArrayList<Container> elements = new ArrayList<Container>();

    // but add subclass ServiceMember
    elements.add(new ServiceMember());

    return elements;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did check other explanations on stack and understood the issue. But I tried a few solutions as well from other posts like but I am not very familiar with Generic so went ahead and asked the question to see if someone can help me in the right way to find a solution to what I am doing.. is there a better way to do this 
    protected ArrayList<? extends Container> elements = new ArrayList<Container>();

Answer (score -1):

You need to *type* `Container`, to indicate the type of things being contained:

```
public class Container<T extends Container<T>> {
    private List<T> elements = new ArrayList<T>();

    public List<T> getElements() {
        return elements;
    }
}

public class Service extends Container<Service> {
}
```

Notes:

- the type `T extends Container<T>` seems extend itself, but this is how you specify it such that you avoid the raw Container type
- the list is *private*: subclasses should simply access it via the getter
- the abstract type `List` is used instead of the concrete implementation `ArrayList`, in line with good practice

Comment: Can you show us how would you instantiate the `Container` class ?