# Parent/Child Generics Relationship

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, generics, parent-child

So, I'm trying to have a parent/child class relationship like this:

```
class ParentClass<C, T> where C : ChildClass<T>
{
    public void AddChild(C child)
    {
        child.SetParent(this); //Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ParentClass<C,T>' to 'ParentClass<ChildClass<T>,T>'
    }
}
class ChildClass<T>
{
    ParentClass<ChildClass<T>, T> myParent;
    public void SetParent(ParentClass<ChildClass<T>, T> parent)
    {
        myParent = parent;
    }
}
```

But, this is a compile error. So, my second thought was to declare the `SetParent` method with a `where`. But the problem is that I don't know what type declare `myParent` as (I know the type, I just son't know how to declare it.)

```
class ParentClass<C, T> where C : ChildClass<T>
{
    public void AddChild(C child)
    {
        child.SetParent(this);
    }
}
class ChildClass<T>
{
    var myParent; //What should I declare this as?
    public void SetParent<K>(ParentClass<K,T> parent) where K : ChildClass<T>
    {
        myParent = parent;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to compile, though it's rather hairbrained:

```
class ParentClass<C, T> where C : ChildClass<C, T>
{
    public void AddChild(C child)
    {
        child.SetParent(this);
    }
}
class ChildClass<C, T> where C : ChildClass<C, T>
{
    ParentClass<C, T> myParent;
    public void SetParent(ParentClass<C, T> parent)
    {
        myParent = parent;
    }
}
```

This solution makes use of a recursively bound type parameter, which *approximates* the "self-type".

I'm obligated to link to Eric Lippert's article on this pattern: [Curiouser and curiouser](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx)

Comment: Ok, but then you get the same problem I had with my second bit of code: how would I declare a variable of either the parent class or the child class?

Comment: I don't think you can. You would need derived classes that resolved the type parameters. I wrote about this pattern (albeit in Java) here, including its pitfalls: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7355094/697449

Comment: Your problem could also be looked at as a design issue, but your question is currently very abstract. Consider updating with the actual use case, and maybe people can chime in on alternatives.

Comment: This works: `class ChildClass<T> : ChildClass<ChildClass<T>, T> { }`. Gives me the functionality I had originally wanted too.

Comment: Oh, I know it's a design issue. At least in the scope I'm using it. It's a bit late for that though. This solution works perfect though.

Comment: The *Curiouser and curiouser* post was exactly what I needed.