# Java generics: Using the type of class an interface is applied to?

Tags: java, generics, interface

I have an interface, whose method could conveniently return the instance on which the method is called. For instance, a setter could return "this".

```
interface OriginWise<T> {
      T setOrigin( Origin origin );
}
```

Is there some way to get an instance of T automatically from the class it's applied to, without passing it as shown below?

```
class MyBean implements OriginWise<MyBean> {
    MyBean setOrigin( Origin o ){ ...; return this; }
}
```

Also, what's the progress with default implementations in interfaces (methods which only use other interface's methods; not the same as abstract class)?

Comment: What do you mean "passing it in as shown below" ? The setter value is being passed into a method. The returnn object is "this". I don't grok.

Comment: I don't really understand the second part of your question ("Also, what's the progress..."), please, reformulate it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to refer to the current type with a type variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354740/is-there-a-way-to-refer-to-the-current-type-with-a-type-variable)

Answer (score 1):

> default implementations in interfaces

- in jdk 8, which you can [download and try out](https://jdk8.java.net/lambda/).

I don't understand the rest of the question, as the code looks good to me.

Answer (score 0):

That's the best you can do. If you want to return this (which implements OriginWise), don't forget to let T extend OriginWise. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354740/is-there-a-way-to-refer-to-the-current-type-with-a-type-variable/7355094#7355094) and http://passion.forco.de/content/emulating-self-types-using-java-generics-simplify-fluent-api-implementation.

Comment: its not a good point; the interface is implented by Mybean. Nothing is supposed to extend originwise.

Comment: @NimChimpsky They're implying that `T` should be a "self type", e.g. `T extends OriginWise<T>`.

Comment: @PaulBellora I know. But that would completely change the functionality.

Comment: @NimChimpsky Would it? That seems to be what the OP's trying to do, for better or worse.

Comment: @PaulBellora yeah maybe actually +1

Comment: `T extends OriginWise<T>` adds no type safety to what's already there