# How to verify the (generic (generic argument))?

Tags: java, class, generics, generic-programming, type-parameter

### Background (that we don't really need to worry about)

This is a question derived from [Build A Generic Tree With Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18399922) . I open this one as a separate question because this is not only related to a Tree problem. This is more a Generic and Class problem instead.

### Question

To be better illustrated by codes, we have a `Tree` class, a `SubTree` class, and a `WrongSubTree` class:

```
class Tree<TREE extends Tree<?,?>, DATA> {
}
class SubTree<STREE extends SubTree<?,?>, DATA> extends Tree<STREE, DATA> {
}
class WrongSubTree<WSTREE extends Tree<?,?>, DATA> extends Tree<WSTREE, DATA> {
}
```

While object creation, we would like to check if the generic argument equals to the class of the object itself:

```
Tree<Tree<?,?>, String> tree01 = new Tree<Tree<?,?>, String>();                 // equals : OK
Tree<SubTree<?,?>, String> tree02 = new Tree<SubTree<?,?>, String>();           // (!) not equals
SubTree<SubTree<?,?>, String> tree03 = new SubTree<SubTree<?,?>, String>();     // equals : OK
WrongSubTree<Tree<?,?>, String> tree04 = new WrongSubTree<Tree<?,?>, String>(); // (!) not equals
```

*(Note that the 4 lines above have no compile errors and no runtime exceptions, for now.)*

### My trial

To do so, we try to add a `Class<>` parameter in the constructors:

```
class Tree<TREE extends Tree<?,?>, DATA> {
    public Tree(Class<TREE> clazz) {
        System.out.println(this.getClass());
        System.out.println(clazz);
        System.out.println();
        if (this.getClass() != clazz)
            throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
class SubTree<STREE extends SubTree<?,?>, DATA> extends Tree<STREE, DATA> {
    public SubTree(Class<STREE> clazz) {
        super(clazz);
    }
}
class WrongSubTree<WSTREE extends Tree<?,?>, DATA> extends Tree<WSTREE, DATA> {
    public WrongSubTree(Class<WSTREE> clazz) {
        super(clazz);
    }
}
```

*(The above class definitions are valid java codes.)*

### Problem

But i don't know how to call that constructor:

```
Tree<Tree<?,?>, String> tree01a = new Tree<Tree<?,?>, String>(Tree.class);
// The constructor Tree<Tree<?,?>,String>(Class<Tree>) is undefined

Tree<Tree<?,?>, String> tree01b = new Tree<Tree<?,?>, String>(Tree<?,?>.class);
// Syntax error, insert "Dimensions" to complete ArrayType
```

Both 2 lines above cause compile-errors.

i guess it is because the constructor `public Tree(Class<TREE> clazz) {}` is expecting `Class<Tree<?,?>>`, but not `Class<Tree>`. However, we cannot do `Tree<?,?>.class`.

The reason is i tried to change the class to:

```
class Tree<TREE extends Tree<?,?>, DATA> {
    public Tree(Class<Tree> clazz) {            // changed
        System.out.println(this.getClass());
        System.out.println(clazz);
        System.out.println();
        if (this.getClass() != clazz)
            throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
Tree<Tree<?,?>, String> tree01a = new Tree<Tree<?,?>, String>(Tree.class);
```

There is no compile-error.

However, the following causes the same compile-error:

```
class Tree<TREE extends Tree<?,?>, DATA> {
    public Tree(Class<Tree<?,?>> clazz) {       // changed
        System.out.println(this.getClass());
        System.out.println(clazz);
        System.out.println();
        if (this.getClass() != clazz)
            throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
Tree<Tree<?,?>, String> tree01a = new Tree<Tree<?,?>, String>(Tree.class);
// The constructor Tree<Tree<?,?>,String>(Class<Tree>) is undefined
```

---

## Edit #1

Based on [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581788/how-to-verify-the-generic-generic-argument#comment27357241_18581788) below, i tried this one. Hope it helps for some inspirations.

```
static class SimpleClass<T> {
    private SimpleClass(Object dummy) {
        // dummy constructor, avoid recursive call of the default constructor
    }
    SimpleClass() {
        SimpleClass<T> myself = new SimpleClass<T>(new Object()) {};
        System.out.println(((ParameterizedType) myself.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
        // prints "T"

        TypeReference<SimpleClass<T>> typeRef = new TypeReference<SimpleClass<T>>() {};
        System.out.println(typeRef.getType());
        // prints "Main.Main$SimpleClass<T>"
    }
    void func() {
        SimpleClass<T> myself = new SimpleClass<T>(new Object()) {};
        System.out.println(((ParameterizedType) myself.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
        // prints "T"

        TypeReference<SimpleClass<T>> typeRef = new TypeReference<SimpleClass<T>>() {};
        System.out.println(typeRef.getType());
        // prints "Main.Main$SimpleClass<T>"
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleClass<String> simpleObj = new SimpleClass<String>();
    simpleObj.func();

    SimpleClass<String> outsideSimpleClass = new SimpleClass<String>(){};
    System.out.println(((ParameterizedType) outsideSimpleClass.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
    // prints "class java.lang.String"
}
```

Note we still **cannot** get "class java.lang.String" **inside** `SimpleClass`.

More importantly, if we use the Type Argument `<T>` to instantiate an object from **another class**, we still cannot get the type parameter from it:

```
static class AnotherClass<T> {
    private AnotherClass(Object dummy) {}
}
static class SimpleClass<T> {
    SimpleClass() {
        AnotherClass<T> another = new AnotherClass<T>(new Object()) {};
        System.out.println(((ParameterizedType) another.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
        // prints "T"

        TypeReference<AnotherClass<T>> anotherTypeRef = new TypeReference<AnotherClass<T>>() {};
        System.out.println(anotherTypeRef.getType());
        // prints "Main.Main$AnotherClass<T>"
    }
    void func() {
        AnotherClass<T> another = new AnotherClass<T>(new Object()) {};
        System.out.println(((ParameterizedType) another.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
        // prints "T"

        TypeReference<AnotherClass<T>> anotherTypeRef = new TypeReference<AnotherClass<T>>() {};
        System.out.println(anotherTypeRef.getType());
        // prints "Main.Main$AnotherClass<T>"
    }
}
```

Note that this means the Type Argument of `AnotherClass` cannot be revealed in `SimpleClass`, **where it is a place outside the class itself!**

To my understanding, we can only use the anonymous sub-class & `getGenericSuperclass()` trick at a place where it actually already know the answer. Such as in `main()`, here is the place where `class java.lang.String` is really defined as the Type Argument.

(IMO, if the ability of this trick is so restricted, it is not really useful at all.)

Comment: It seems like you would want to use a "super type token" pattern, e.g. [Guava's `TypeToken`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ReflectionExplained).

Comment: @PaulBellora Thanks for your reply. I am still looking into the `TypeToken`. Meanwhile, i found a workaround for my question above, which is: `Tree<Tree<?,?>, String> tree01a = new Tree<Tree<?,?>, String>((Class<Tree<?, ?>>) Class.forName(Tree.class.getName()));`. It is very long, but it does the job. However, more importantly, i discovered [this class checking can be hacked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18582360/generic-type-argument-checked-by-class-parameter-can-be-hacked-any-better-ways)!!!

Comment: Ignoring the problematic recursive type parameters, `TypeToken` seems to fit the bill. If it (or another implementation of super type tokens) doesn't work, please update the question explaining why.

Comment: if you change your constructor to `public Tree(Class<? extends Tree> clazz) {...}`
 you should be able to call it `Tree<>(Tree.class)`

Comment: @user902383, Yes. But keep it to `public Tree(Class<TREE> clazz) {...}`, the Type Parameter `TREE` will be forced to update to the sub-classes respectively. And all the constructors of `Tree` are having this check, omit the zero-argument constructor. So all sub-classes of `Tree` are forced to call the super constructor and go through this check. However, [this check is not reliable](stackoverflow.com/questions/18582360). Inspired by @Paul and the [TypeToken](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ReflectionExplained), i am trying to check by the return type of a public method.

Comment: Dear @PaulBellora, to my understanding, the `TypeToken` is playing with the anonymous sub-class `new IKnowMyType<String>() {}.type` thing and probably using `getGenericSuperclass()` and cast it to `ParameterizedType` in its implementation. It actually goes back the question [How to get the Generic Type Parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337530) Both `TypeToken` and `TypeReference` works **outside** the class itself. But can we get the dynamically assigned Type Argument's class **right inside the class's constructor/method**? (many people said can't though.)

Comment: @PaulBellora: Updated my question above. Would you please have a look? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @midnite You can with Guava's `TypeToken` by using [`new TypeToken<T>(getClass()) { }`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html#TypeToken\(java.lang.Class\)), but only if that call happens in an instance whose runtime type has resolved `T`, for example `class SimpleClassChild extends SimpleClass<String>`.

Comment: @PaulBellora, Yes. Only at where the runtime type has resolved, we can get the actual (String) class. I have spent all the night studying n trying on Guava's `TypeToken` and about to give up on this now. i kind of accept it is impossible to get the Generic Argument at where the runtime type is not resolved. Thanks for your kindly helps!! In fact i am building a [Tree with inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18399922) - which requires structure like [your answer there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7355094/697449). I won't give up on the Tree. I guess it's time for me to re-think. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [TypeTools](https://github.com/jhalterman/typetools) (which I authored) for this. Example:

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>() {};
Class<?> stringType = TypeResolver.resolveRawArgument(List.class, stringList.getClass());
assert stringType == String.class;
```