# Passing generic subtype class information to superclass in Java

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, abstract-class

I've long used an idiom in Java for using the class information of a (non-abstract) class in the methods of its (generally abstract) ancestor class(es) (unfortunately I can't find the name of this pattern):

```
public abstract class Abstract<T extends Abstract<T>> {
    private final Class<T> subClass;

    protected Abstract(Class<T> subClass) {
        this.subClass = subClass;
    }

    protected T getSomethingElseWithSameType() {
        ....
    }
}
```

An example of a subclass thereof:

```
public class NonGeneric extends Abstract<NonGeneric> {
    public NonGeneric() {
        super(NonGeneric.class);
    }
}
```

However, I'm having trouble defining a subclass of `Abstract` which has its own generic parameters:

```
public class Generic<T> extends Abstract<Generic<T>> {
    public Generic() {
        super(Generic.class);
    }
}
```

This example is not compilable; likewise, it is not possible to specify the generic types using e.g. `Generic<T>.class` or even to use a wildcard like `Generic<?>`.

I also tried replacing the declaration of generic type `T` in the superclass to `? extends T`, but that isn't compilable either.

Is there any way I can get this pattern to work with generic base classes?

Comment: `I can't find the name of this pattern`: Sounds like its `Strategy pattern`

Comment: It's not a pattern, it's an idiom in java, potentially to circumvent the poor generics implementation... And no idea how it's called.

Comment: I think you're looking for the [curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) - i.e. the "self-type". Java doesn't support the self type and it [can only be approximated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354740/is-there-a-way-to-refer-to-the-current-type-with-a-type-variable/7355094#7355094).

Comment: "I've long used a design pattnern" There is no such pattern in Java. What you are doing can be done with `public abstract class Abstract<T>`

Comment: I have pretty much rewritten the code in my answer - there's now a cast-free solution there for you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The "pattern" (idiom) of passing an instance of `Class<T>` (typically to the constructor) is using [Class Literals as Runtime-Type Tokens](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html), and is used to keep a runtime reference to the generic type, which is otherwise erased.

The solution is firstly to change the token class bound to:

```
Class<? extends T>
```

and then to put a similar requirement on your generic subclass as you did with your super class; have the concrete class pass a type token, but you can type it properly as a parameter:

These classes compile without casts or warnings:

```
public abstract class Abstract<T extends Abstract<T>> {
    private final Class<? extends T> subClass;

    protected Abstract(Class<? extends T> subClass) {
        this.subClass = subClass;
    }
}

public class NonGeneric extends Abstract<NonGeneric> {
    public NonGeneric() {
        super(NonGeneric.class);
    }
}

public class Generic<T> extends Abstract<Generic<T>> {
    public Generic(Class<? extends Generic<T>> clazz) {
        super(clazz);
    }
}
```

And finally at the concrete class, if you declare the usage as its own class, it doesn't require a cast anywhere:

```
public class IntegerGeneric extends Generic<Integer> {
    public IntegerGeneric() {
        super(IntegerGeneric.class);
    }
}
```

---

I haven't figured out how to create an instance of `Generic` (anonymous or not) without a cast:

```
// can someone fill in the parameters without a cast?
new Generic<Integer>(???);     // typed direct instance
new Generic<Integer>(???) { }; // anonymous
```

I don't think it's possible, but I welcome being shown otherwise.

Comment: I thought of this way, but then you have to perform cast while passing argument to the constructor anyway. I guess cast cannot be avoided. If you can find some way without cast, that would be appreciable. :)

Comment: @RohitJain this does not require a cast if you declare concrete impls as their own class - see edit. I think you would need a cast for an anonymous impl or an instance of Generic itself.

Comment: Did you mean `extends Generic<GenericFoo>`?

Comment: @RohitJain It compiles now. The change was to the parameter type of the sub class's constructor to be `Class<Generic<Integer>>`. So you *can* declare a subclass without any casting.

Comment: @RohitJain Finally, I've cracked it :)

Comment: @PaulBellora A new, better approach f you're interested

Comment: @Bohemian Looks pretty. +1 I give you for this. It comes to the usage of subclass to avoid casting. But still this is applausable :)

Comment: +1 Looks good. For the anonymous conundrum at the end, I think you meant `new Generic<Integer>(???) { };` (and no it's not possible).

Answer (score 3):

The major problem you have got here is, there is no class literal for concrete parameterized type. And that makes sense, since parameterized types don't have any runtime type information. So, you can only have class literal with raw types, in this case `Generic.class`.

**Reference:**

- [Java Generics FAQs](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html)

  - [Why is there no class literal for concrete parameterized types?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#Why%20is%20there%20no%20class%20literal%20for%20the%20concrete%20instantiation%20of%20a%20parameterized%20type?) :

Well, that's fine, but `Generic.class` gives you a `Class<Generic>` which is not compatible with `Class<Generic<T>>`. A workaround is to find a way to convert it to `Class<Generic<T>>`, but that too you can't do directly. You would have to add an intermediate cast to `Class<?>`, which represents the family of all the instantiation of `Class`. And then downcast to `Class<Generic<T>>`, which will remove the compiler error, though you will an unchecked cast warning. You can annotate the constructor with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` to remove the warning.

```
class Generic<T> extends Abstract<Generic<T>> {     
    public Generic() {
        super((Class<Generic<T>>)(Class<?>)Generic.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Bohemian Even I didn't find myself using it before today itself. IMO, I refrain from framing such a complex generic structure, which would force me to do something like this. In other words, I like to treat my fellow programmer's well. ;)

Comment: fyi I think I figured out a cleaner way - see my answer

Answer (score -1):

There is no need in `Class<T> subClass` argument. Change:

```
protected Abstract(Class<T> subClass) {
    this.subClass = subClass;
}
```

to:

```
protected Abstract(Class subClass) {
    this.subClass = subClass;
}
```

and everything will compile.

Comment: That works in most cases, but in my specific case, I also use the `Class` object to dynamically cast to `T`, which also gets ugly.

The more I use other languages, the more I realise how messed up Java generics are.

Comment: Do not overuse generics, this is not a panacea. They just help to develop, no more.