# Uses of recursive type bounds

Tags: java, extends

A friend of mine found this tidbit in the Java API (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html),

```
Class Enum<E extends Enum<E>>
```

and by reading the following article https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html I could understand what the aforementioned line entailed syntactically but from the examples given I could not figure out a use case for this beyond the Enum class (reviewed the source).

I'd like to learn more about possible problems where the above may present a solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's for example useful to to allow subclasses to use their own type

Imagine a class like

```
class Node {
    Node next;
}
```

if you extend that class, you're stuck with `Node`.

```
class SpecialNode extends Node {
    void foo() {
        // euwww
        SpecialNode nextNode = (SpecialNode) this.next;
    }
}
```

You also can't just define it like

```
class Node<T> {
    T next;
}
```

because that would allow anything for `T`. You really want a `T` that `extends Node` or you can no longer use T as `Node` from within `Node` without casting. It would work for child classes though.

By using recursive bounds like

```
class Node<T extends Node<T>> {
    T next;
}
```

You limit T to yourself or subclasses of yourself which then allows you to do

```
class SpecialNode extends Node<SpecialNode> {
    void foo() {
        SpecialNode nextNode = this.next; // type-safe!
    }
}
```

That way both parent and child class can access everything on their abstraction level fully typesafe.

Answer (score 4):

This idiom almost always means *'E should be the type of the subclass'*. For example, you might notice that Enum `implements Comparable<E>`.

When the class is extended, you get to something like:

```
//         E extends Enum<E> ┐
class AnEnum extends Enum<AnEnum> {...}
```

Now AnEnum is also a `Comparable<AnEnum>` and [`getDeclaringClass`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#getDeclaringClass()) returns a `Class<AnEnum>`.

I've seen this idiom related to the [curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). The intent is that the superclass can refer to the subclass generically.

(Due to the fact that the subclass of Enum is generated by the compiler, I don't think there is actually a reason Enum in particular needed to be declared this way. It could have just been `Enum<E>`.)

Comment: This is the right pattern used, not the one in my answer +1

Answer (score 2):

Generally it's useful for defining some behavior in a superclass (e.g. in `Enum`) which depends on type information specific to a subtype of the class in question ([I actually asked a similar question a wee while ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19312641/passing-generic-subtype-class-information-to-superclass-in-java)).

Comment: I don't think this question is the same as your question. (This one doesn't have anything to do with class literals.)

Comment: Yeah, I suppose I jumped a bit too far ahead. Nevertheless, it is still passing information about the subtype to the superclass, albeit only at compile time (e.g. for method signatures).

Comment: P.S. Should I delete the answer since I admit it's incorrect, or should it stay?-- I've never figured out this whole thing...

Comment: I would just edit out your first sentence. Your answer seems fine to me.