# Recursive Generic and Fluent Interface

Tags: java, generics, fluent-interface, nested-generics

**tl;dr**

Trying to implement a hierarchal fluent interface such that I can combine *nodes* child classes while also the class standalone, but getting type parameter is not within its bound errors.

**Details**

I'm trying to achieve a solution so that I can create something such that I can do something like:

```
farm
    .animal()
        .cat()
            .meow()
            .findsHuman()
                .saysHello()
                .done()
            .done()
        .dog()
            .bark()
            .chacesCar()
            .findsHuman()
                .saysHello()
                .done()
            .done()
        .done()
    .human()
        .saysHello()
        .done();
```

while also being able to do:

```
Human human = new Human()
    .saysHello()
```

I've gotten close using various strategies but haven't been able to gain the flexibility described.

My current attempt uses the following classes:

```
abstract class Base<T extends Base<T>>{

    private T parent;

    Base(){

    }

    Base( T parent ){
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public T done() throws NullPointerException{
        if ( parent != null ){
            return (T) parent;
        }

        throw new NullPointerException();
    }   
}

class Farm<T extends Base<T>> extends Base{

    private Animal<Farm<T>> animal;
    private Human<Farm<T>> human;

    public Farm(){
        super();
        this.animal = new Animal( this );
        this.human = new Human( this );
    }

    public Animal<Farm> animal(){
        return this.animal;
    }

    public Human<Farm<T>> human(){
        return this.human;
    }
}

class Animal <T extends Base<T>> extends Base{

    private Cat<Animal<T>> cat;
    private Dog<Animal<T>> dog;

    public Animal(){
        super();
        init();
    }

    public Animal( T parent ){
        super( parent );
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        this.cat = new Cat(this);
        this.dog = new Dog(this);
    }

    public Cat<Animal<T>> cat(){
        return cat;
    }

    public Dog<Animal<T>> dog(){
        return dog;
    }
}

class Human<T extends Base<T>> extends Base{

    public Human<T> saysHello(){
        System.out.println("human says hi");
        return this;
    }
}

class Cat <T extends Base<T>> extends Base{

    private Human<Cat> human;

    public Cat(){
        super();
        init();
    }

    public Cat( T parent ){
        super( parent );
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        this.human = new Human();
    }

    public Cat<T> meow(){
        System.out.println("cat says meow");
        return this;
    }

    public Human<Cat<T>> findsHuman(){
        return this.human;
    }
}


class Dog <T extends Base<T>> extends Base{

    private Human<Dog> human;

    public Dog(){
        super();
        init();
    }

    public Dog( T parent ){
        super( parent );
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        this.human = new Human();
    }


    public Dog<T> bark(){
        System.out.println("dog says woof");
        return this;
    }

    public Dog<T> chacesCar(){
        System.out.println("cat drinks milk");
        return this;
    }

    public Human<Dog<T>> findsHuman(){
        return this.human;
    }

}
```

The errors I'm seeing are commonly:

> Animal.java:4: type parameter Animal is not within its bound private Cat cat;
>   Animal.java:5: type parameter Animal is not within its bound private Dog dog;

Applied to all similar references and also pertaining to my example desired case:

> cannot find symbol
>   symbol  : method dog()
>   location: class Base.dog()

I've tried using the following solutions which seemed to tackle similar problems, but to no avail, so any and all support is welcome.

*References*

- [Is there a way to refer to the current type with a type variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354740/is-there-a-way-to-refer-to-the-current-type-with-a-type-variable/7354847#7354847)
- http://vyazelenko.com/2012/03/02/recursive-generics-to-the-rescue/

Comment: IMHO you are using _java_ generics for what they are not designed. This would work fine in C++, but java generics _are not_ the same. _Generics are Harmful_, and this is one example. Surely there are other *software engineering* solutions for your needs, instead of the *programming art* you are pasting.
When things are so much complex as the answers shown here, probably something is wrong.

Comment: I think I found a solution. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @AlfonsoNishikawa I concur that it may be pushing the limits of this pattern, and was beyond some of my initial understanding's so thought I'd ask for the communities thoughts.

Comment: @morpheus05 Thank you for the update, I will go through all answers and see if I can find one that best solves me issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code below seems to work fine and doesn't need any `@SuppressWarnings`. The key concept to grasp is that your `T` parameter is effectively the class of your object's parent, but `T`'s parent could be anything. So instead of `T extends Base<T>` you want `T extends Base<?>`.

The output is:

```
cat says meow
human says hi
dog says woof
cat drinks milk
human says hi
human says hi
```

...which I believe is correct, although you might want to change your `Dog.chacesCar()` method so it doesn't output `cat drinks milk`! Also it should be `chases` not `chaces`.

Hope this helps!

```
abstract class Base<T extends Base<?>> {

    private final T parent;

    Base() {
        this.parent = null;
    }

    Base(T parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public T done() throws NullPointerException {
        if (parent != null) {
            return parent;
        }

        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
}

class Farm<T extends Base<?>> extends Base<T> {

    private final Animal<Farm<T>> animal;
    private final Human<Farm<T>> human;

    public Farm() {
        super();
        this.animal = new Animal<>(this);
        this.human = new Human<>(this);
    }

    public Animal<Farm<T>> animal() {
        return this.animal;
    }

    public Human<Farm<T>> human() {
        return this.human;
    }
}

class Animal<T extends Base<?>> extends Base<T> {

    private Cat<Animal<T>> cat;
    private Dog<Animal<T>> dog;

    public Animal() {
        super();
        init();
    }

    public Animal(T parent) {
        super(parent);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        this.cat = new Cat<>(this);
        this.dog = new Dog<>(this);
    }

    public Cat<Animal<T>> cat() {
        return cat;
    }

    public Dog<Animal<T>> dog() {
        return dog;
    }
}

class Human<T extends Base<?>> extends Base<T> {
    public Human() {
        super();
    }

    public Human(T parent) {
        super(parent);
    }

    public Human<T> saysHello() {
        System.out.println("human says hi");
        return this;
    }
}

class Cat<T extends Base<?>> extends Base<T> {

    private Human<Cat<T>> human;

    public Cat() {
        super();
        init();
    }

    public Cat(T parent) {
        super(parent);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        this.human = new Human<>(this);
    }

    public Cat<T> meow() {
        System.out.println("cat says meow");
        return this;
    }

    public Human<Cat<T>> findsHuman() {
        return this.human;
    }
}

class Dog<T extends Base<?>> extends Base<T> {

    private Human<Dog<T>> human;

    public Dog() {
        super();
        init();
    }

    public Dog(T parent) {
        super(parent);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        this.human = new Human<>(this);
    }

    public Dog<T> bark() {
        System.out.println("dog says woof");
        return this;
    }

    public Dog<T> chacesCar() {
        System.out.println("cat drinks milk");
        return this;
    }

    public Human<Dog<T>> findsHuman() {
        return this.human;
    }

}
```

Test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Farm<?> farm = new Farm<>();
    farm
        .animal()
            .cat()
                .meow()
                .findsHuman()
                    .saysHello()
                    .done()
                .done()
            .dog()
                .bark()
                .chacesCar()
                .findsHuman()
                    .saysHello()
                    .done()
                .done()
            .done()
        .human()
            .saysHello()
            .done();

    Human human = new Human()
            .saysHello();
}
```

Comment: Could you please share your main method, when trying I'm running into cannot find symbol errors

Comment: I've added it to the answer (it was pretty much the exact test code you had posted).

Comment: What symbol is it not finding?

Comment: Thank you, seems like my problem was I was running Farm without <?> which was causing done to return Base. 

This seems to resolve my problem and give me the direction I needed.

Comment: The *thing* with `SuppressWarnings` in other answers is there to solve class hierarchy and template methods. For example you have to reimplement `findsHuman()` in both `Cat` and `Dog` instead of implementing it in the `Animal` class. Nevertheless +1 for approaching the question from the other way around.

Comment: To be more clear - you have changed the semantics of the generic parameter from *"being the leaf child type"* to *"being the owning builder type"* (that is what I meant by *approach from the other way around*).

Answer (score 3):

The best thing I came up is the following:

```
new Animal()
    .cat()
      .meow()
      .findsHuman()
        .<Cat>done()
      .<Animal>done()
    .dog()
      .bark()
        .findHuman()
          .<Dog>done()
      .done();
```

With the following base class:

```
public abstract class Base<T extends Base<T>>{

  private Base<?> backRef;

  public Base() {}

  public Base(Base<?> backRef) {
    this.backRef = backRef;
 }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected T self() {
    return (T)this;
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public <U extends Base<U>> U done() {
    return (U)backRef;
  }
}
```

If you declare backRef as of Type T then the other classes are not allowed because they are not a subclasses of each other, so you have to specify a different type, but since this type is context dependent (one time its Cat, one time its Dog) I don't see an alternative as to pass a hint.

**I found a solution:**

```
new Animal()
    .cat()
      .meow()
      .findsHuman()
        .done()
      .done()
    .dog()
      .bark()
        .findHuman()
          .done()
    .done();



public abstract class Base<T extends Base<T,P>, P>{

  private P backRef;
  public Base() {}

  public Base(P backRef) {
    this.backRef = backRef;
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  protected T self() {
    return (T)this;
  }

  public P done() {
    return backRef;
 }
}
```

Like someone suggested, we add an additional Type for the parent.

Now the base classes:

```
public final class Cat extends Base<Cat, Animal>{

  public Cat() {}

  public Cat(Animal backRef) {
    super(backRef);
  }

  public Cat meow() {
    System.out.println("Meeeoooww");
    return self();
  }

  public Human<Cat> findsHuman() {
    return new Human<Cat>(this);
  }
}
```

As you can see, Cat clearly specifies which base type it should use. Now for human, which can change the type depending on the context:

```
public final class Human<P> extends Base<Human<P>, P> {

  public Human() {}

  public Human(P backRef) {
    super(backRef);
  }
```

}

Human specifies an additional generic which the caller (Cat, Dog) specifies in their findHuman() Method.

Comment: That is quite interesting use of type hints (although the type safety of this is not that good). +1

Comment: Congratulations. I hope I will never need something like this ;) But good job. Personally, I could never get into the solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is what we did on one our project:

```
public abstract class Parent<T extends Parent<T>> {

    /**
     * Get {@code this} casted to its subclass.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected final T self() {
        return (T) this;
    }

    public T foo() {
        // ... some logic
        return self();
    }

    // ... other parent methods

}
```

---

```
public class Child extends Parent<Child> {

    public Child bar() {
        // ... some logic
        return self();
    }

    // ... other child methods

}
```

---

Allowing child to have its own subclass would be:

```
public class Child<T extends Child<T>> extends Parent<T> {

    public T bar() {
        // ... some logic
        return self();
    }

}
```

Comment: the implementation of `self` should probably be final so no one else messes around with that.

Comment: This would not work for `OtherChild extends Parent<Child>` - the `(T) this` in `self()` would fail.

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
class Farm<T extends Base<T>>
```

The compiler treats the second type parameter as a concrete class. For example, say if you replaced that line with this:

```
class Farm<T extends Base<Double>>
```

'Double' is a concrete class. When the compiler scans this, it cannot tell the difference between your T and Double, and such treats them both as concrete class, and not type parameters. The only way to let the compiler know T is a type parameter is this way:

```
class Farm<T extends Base<T>, T>
```

I hope this answers (or is at least relevant) to your question.

**edit**
Post was edited while I was typing, so I guess this answer isn't relevant anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You could also play with interfaces, so that you can fake multiple inheritance. A bit verbose, but there is no hazardous casting, and I find it quite understandable.

---

**Define the available methods:**

```java
public interface AnimalIn {
    AnimalOut animal();
}

public interface CatIn {
    CatOut cat();
}

public interface MeowIn {
    CatOut meow();
}

public interface DogIn {
    DogOut dog();
}

public interface BarkIn {
    DogOut bark();
}

public interface ChacesCarIn {
    DogOut chacesCar();
}

public interface FindsHumanIn<T> {
    HumanOut<T> findsHuman();
}

public interface HumanIn {
    HumanOut<FarmOut> human();
}

public interface SaysHelloIn<T> {
    HumanOut<T> saysHello();
}

public interface DoneIn<T> {
    T done();
}
```

You may need to have multiple methods in an interface, but I haven't met this need yet. For example, if you had had to kinds of `meow`s:

```java
public interface MeowIn {
    CatOut meowForFood();
    CatOut meowForMilk();
    CatOut meowForStrokes();
}
```

---

**Define the output types:**

`Farm` provides `Animal` or `Human`:

```java
public interface FarmOut extends AnimalIn, HumanIn {
    // no specific methods
}
```

`Animal` provides `Cat`, `Dog` or `Done`:

```java
public interface AnimalOut extends CatIn, DogIn, DoneIn<FarmOut> {
    // no specific methods
}
```

`Cat` provides `Meow`, `FindsHuman` or `Done`:

```java
public interface CatOut extends MeowIn, FindsHumanIn<CatOut>, DoneIn<AnimalOut> {
    // no specific methods
}
```

`Dog` provides `Bark`, `ChacesCar`, `FindsHuman` or `Done`:

```java
public interface DogOut extends BarkIn, ChacesCarIn, FindsHumanIn<DogOut>, DoneIn<AnimalOut> {
    // no specific methods
}
```

`Human` provides `SayHello` or `Done`:

```java
public interface HumanOut<T> extends SaysHelloIn<T>, DoneIn<T> {
    // no specific methods
}
```

---

**Simply implement the *Out interfaces:**

```java
public class Farm implements FarmOut {

    @Override
    public AnimalOut animal() {
        return new Animal(this);
    }

    @Override
    public HumanOut<FarmOut> human() {
        return new Human<FarmOut>(this);
    }

}

public class Animal implements AnimalOut {

    private FarmOut chain;

    public Animal(FarmOut chain) {
        this.chain = chain;
    }

    @Override
    public CatOut cat() {
        return new Cat(this);
    }

    @Override
    public DogOut dog() {
        return new Dog(this);
    }

    @Override
    public FarmOut done() {
        return chain;
    }

}

public class Dog implements DogOut {

    private AnimalOut chain;

    public Dog(AnimalOut chain) {
        this.chain = chain;
    }

    @Override
    public DogOut bark() {
        System.out.println("bark");
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public DogOut chacesCar() {
        System.out.println("chaces car");
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public HumanOut<DogOut> findsHuman() {
        return new Human<DogOut>(this);
    }

    @Override
    public AnimalOut done() {
        return chain;
    }

}

public class Cat implements CatOut {

    private AnimalOut chain;

    public Cat(AnimalOut chain) {
        this.chain = chain;
    }

    @Override
    public CatOut meow() {
        System.out.println("meow");
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public HumanOut<CatOut> findsHuman() {
        return new Human<CatOut>(this);
    }

    @Override
    public AnimalOut done() {
        return chain;
    }

}

public class Human<T> implements HumanOut<T> {

    private T chain;

    public Human(T chain) {
        this.chain = chain;
    }

    @Override
    public HumanOut<T> saysHello() {
        System.out.println("hello");
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public T done() {
        return chain;
    }

}
```

Those implementations would work also without the interfaces: remove the `implements *Out`, the `@Override`s, and replace any `*Out` by `*` (e.g. `AnimalOut` by `Animal`). That said, it's easier to maintain with the interfaces: simply update them and fix your compilation errors. It's also easier to find DSL solutions with interfaces (as you can see), and they are sometimes simply necessary.

---

**Demo:**

```java
new Farm()
.animal()
    .cat()
        .meow()
        .findsHuman()
            .saysHello()
            .done()
        .done()
    .dog()
        .bark()
        .chacesCar()
        .findsHuman()
            .saysHello()
            .done()
        .done()
    .done()
.human()
    .saysHello()
    .done();
```

Prints:

```
meow
hello
bark
chaces car
hello
hello
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the method done should return the parent, but the parent is not necessarily a T but is just a Base. And the other problem is that whatever the class is, the `done` method should always return the same class.

But here is a slight variation of your proposed classes. First for `Base` declaring its concrete class and its concrete parent :

```
abstract class Base<T extends Base<T, P>, P>{

    private P parent;

    Base(){

    }

    Base( P parent ){
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public P done() throws NullPointerException{
        if ( parent != null ){
            return parent;
        }

        throw new NullPointerException();
    }   
}
```

That being done, the derived concrete classes become :

```
class Farm extends Base<Farm, Object>{

    private Animal animal;
    private Human human;

    public Farm(){
        super();
        this.animal = new Animal( this );
        this.human = new Human( this );
    }

    public Animal animal(){
        return this.animal;
    }

    public Human human(){
        return this.human;
    }
}

class Animal extends Base<Animal, Farm>{

    private Cat cat;
    private Dog dog;

    public Animal(){
        super();
        init();
    }

    public Animal( Farm parent ){
        super( parent );
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        this.cat = new Cat(this);
        this.dog = new Dog(this);
    }

    public Cat cat(){
        return cat;
    }

    public Dog dog(){
        return dog;
    }
}

class Human extends Base<Human, Farm>{

    public Human() {

    }

    public Human(Farm farm) {
        super(farm);
    }

    public Human saysHello(){
        System.out.println("human says hi");
        return this;
    }

}

class CatOrDog extends Base<Cat, Animal>{

    protected Human human;

    public CatOrDog(){
        super();
        init(null);
    }

    public CatOrDog( Animal parent ){
        super( parent );
        init(parent);
    }

    private void init(Animal parent){
        Animal parent = done();
        Farm farm = (parent == null) ? null : parent.done();
        this.human = new Human(farm);
    }

    public Human findsHuman(){
        return this.human;
    }
}


class Cat extends CatOrDog{

    public Cat(){
        super();
    }

    public Cat( Animal parent ){
        super( parent );
    }

    public Cat meow(){
        System.out.println("cat says meow");
        return this;
    }
}


class Dog extends CatOrDog {

    public Dog(){
        super();
    }

    public Dog( Animal parent ){
        super( parent );
    }

    public Dog bark(){
        System.out.println("dog says woof");
        return this;
    }

    public Dog chacesCar(){
        System.out.println("cat drinks milk");
        return this;
    }
}
```

With that, I could write without any error or warning :

```
Farm farm = new Farm();
farm.animal()
    .cat()
        .meow()
        .findsHuman()
            .saysHello()
            .done()
        .animal()
    .dog()
        .bark()
        .chacesCar()
        .findsHuman()
            .saysHello()
            .done()
        .animal()
    .done()
.human()
    .saysHello()
    .done();
```

But note that I had to replace to `done` calls with `animals` calls.

Edit :

I added a new class `CatOrDog` to factorize the `Human` processing. As the parent of a `Human` is a `Farm`, I initialize the new `human` with a correct parent if it exists. That way, not only the above sources compiles without error or warning, but it also runs without any problem and it prints :

```
cat says meow
human says hi
dog says woof
cat drinks milk
human says hi
human says hi
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "safe" way to do this, but this should compile:

```
class Dog extends Base{

 <T extends Dog> T bark(){
    return (T) this;
 } 

}
```