# Java generic casting

Tags: java, generics, types, casting

I have a generic class `A<T>` and a subclass B extends `A<String>`.
The class A have a method which returns this (so an `A<T>`).
The problem is, if I call the method on a B object, it will return a `A<String>` and I have to cast to B, but B is the same as `A<String>`, isn't it ? So I shouldn't have to cast ...

Comment: is a `porsche` the same as a every `car`?

Comment: Please show your code... it sounds like you can use a covariant return type.

Comment: You need the [return SELF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354740/is-there-a-way-to-refer-to-the-current-type-with-a-type-variable) pattern. It's a bit ugly, but works. This is an example of the [curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your method returns `A<String>` it **can** be an object of type `B` *but it does not have to be!*

If you have a superclass of type `car` and `BMW extends car`.

Consider a factory that creates a car.
**The method returns car** - *this can be a BMW but it does not have to be a BMW*.

Comment: Because I could create another class which also extends A<String>, I have only one so I did not see that ...

Comment: @L.DUPRÉBERTONI this isn't really an answer to the question, which has a good solution. If I know that I have a `B`, and a method in the superclass returns `this`, then I would expect it to return a `B`; but the method will actually return an `A<String>`. The way around this is the curiously recurring template pattern.

Comment: @BoristheSpider the question was about the understanding why he has to cast - I think I clearly answered this question. If you find yourself having another question feel free to post it as an answer to his question

Comment: The point is that "_[t]he class `A` have a method which returns `this`_". If have created a `new B()` then we know that `this` can never by _anything else_. This answer answers a different question, not the question asked. I believe that the OP doesn't really understand the problem, and has selected the wrong answer...

Answer (score 0):

I overrided the method and cast the returned value so that I don't have to do it everywhere. Thanks @AndyTurner

Answer (score 0):

You don't even have to cast. You can override the method and change the return type to B, as it's still an `A<String>` which is an `A<T>`, so it's valid for B.

```
class A<T> {

    public A<T> return_this() {
        return this;
    }

}

class B extends A<String> {

    @Override
    public B return_this() {
        return this;
    }


}
```

So you can do this:

```
B b = new B();
A<String> a = b.return_this(); //Because B extends A<String>
B b = b.return_this();
```

Comment: This does work, but becomes quickly untenable if there are large number of methods.

Comment: You can do this, or you can cast each time you call a method.

Comment: As I said it depends. This solution is simple and works when you have one or two methods and one or two classes in the hierarchy. It becomes unmaintainable if there are a large number of methods returning self types; such as in a fluent accessor or builder pattern. In that case the curiously recurring template pattern is required. Casting is never an option however.