# Is there ever a reason to implement java.util.Comparable for a type other than itself?

Tags: java

Classes implementing `Comparable<T>` typically implement it for themselves, e.g.

```
class MyInteger implements Comparable<MyInteger> { ... }
class MyString implements Comparable<MyString> { ... }
```

But there's nothing to stop you implementing it for a different type:

```
class MyString implements Comparable<MyInteger> { ... }
```

which would allow you to compare a `MyString` to a `MyInteger`.

As is described [in the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), `Comparable` is intended to model the natural ordering, which is a [total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order), and so to be able to have anti-symmetry, the type of the argument of `compareTo` should be the same as the type on which that method is defined.

But are there any practical uses (abuses) of implementing `class SomeType implements Comparable<OtherType>`?

---

**Update**: The answers that [Joni](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41759978/3788176) and [I](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41760105/3788176) have provided give practical examples of where `Comparable<Supertype>` are implemented implicitly, i.e. where your classes implement that interface transitively. It would be interesting to know if anybody has an example where it might be used *explicitly*.

Comment: I can imagine `implements Comparable<SuperType>` being useful, but not `implements Comparable<UnrelatedType>`

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is to implement it for a superclass, such as `class MyInteger implements Comparable<Number>`.

Comment: @khelwood but taking that to its limit, `implements Comparable<Object>` isn't useful.

Comment: No, but if your `SuperType` is already comparable to itself, implementing `Comparable<SuperType>` on a subtype would allow you to refine the way your subtype was ordered (inside a collection of `SuperType`) as long as it didn't contradict the `SuperType` ordering.

Comment: @khelwood That would be pretty useless. You would be overriding the `compareTo` method just to give it the exact same implementation as what was in the `SuperType`.

Comment: @4castle actually, it's not totally useless. Answer forthcoming...

Comment: @4castle By "not contradict", I mean "combines in a well-defined way". It can be more discriminating.

Comment: Presumably the actual reason `Comparable` accepts a type parameter is so that `compareTo(T)` as specified in the interface can have the correct argument type.

Comment: @khelwood yes - but the onus is on you to make it the same type. There are two parts to that: firstly, it would be nice if there were a way to refer to the [self type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354740/is-there-a-way-to-refer-to-the-current-type-with-a-type-variable); but since you can't enforce the use of the self type, the question is whether there is a benefit to that lack of enforcement.

Answer (score 4):

If there is a parent/child relationship you do find this. For example, the Enum class implements `Comparable<E>` with E being a type parameter. All enums share this one compareTo implementation.

To clarify: `Enum<ConcreteClass>` implements `Comparable<ConcreteClass>`. If it followed the pattern you'd expect it to implement `Comparable<Enum<ConcreteClass>>`

Comment: `E` is the type parameter, but it's always the self type.

Comment: No, E is a subtype of Enum. Added a remark that hopefully clarifies

Answer (score 4):

The obvious (in hindsight) case where you encounter this is in subclasses of classes implementing `Comparable`:

```
abstract class Superclass implements Comparable<Superclass> {}
abstract class Subclass extends Superclass {}

System.out.println(Subclass.class.getGenericInterfaces()[0]);
// Prints Comparable<Superclass>
```

As ever, there is a great insight in Bloch's *Effective Java 2nd Ed*, in Item 8 "Consider implementing Comparable":

> One consequence of these three provisions [of the `compareTo` contract] is that the equality test imposed by
>   a compareTo method must obey the same restrictions imposed by the equals contract:
>   reflexivity, symmetry, and transitivity. Therefore the same caveat applies:
>   there is no way to extend an instantiable class with a new value component while
>   preserving the compareTo contract, unless you are willing to forgo the benefits of
>   object-oriented abstraction (Item 8).

So, what this says is that *provided your subclass doesn't have any more values than the superclass used to determine ordering*, implementing `Comparable<Supertype>` is reasonable.

The implication of this, in addition to the general requirements of the `Comparable`, is that `Comparable<Superclass>` should be implemented identically in `Superclass` and all subclasses.

That suggests that `compareTo` should be marked `final`, if `Superclass` is a class. If it's an interface, you could provide a default implementation in Java 8+; but there's no (in-built) way to enforce that the method is not overridden differently in implementing classes.