# What should compareTo() return if argument is different implementation of the same interface?

Tags: java, interface, comparable

Having interface

```
interface Animal extends Comparable<Animal> {
}
```

and 2 classes

```
class Dog implements Animal {

}
```

and

```
class Cat implements Animal {

}
```

What `compareTo(Animal o)` should return when arguement is not the same concrete implementation of `Animal`?

Should it throw `IllegalArgumentException`?

As example if I pass `Dog` instance to `Cat.compareTo()`. I can not compare them as they are different types. I can not refer to `super.compareTo()` as their super is `Object` type which doesn't implement `Comparable`. Casting `Dog` to `Cat` will throw `ClassCastException`.

Comment: If you can't compare cats and dogs the interface definition is wrong (since it claims that you can compare any animal to any other).

Comment: If you are planning to (for instance) put a bunch of different animals in a list and sort them, then all `Animal` should be comparable to each other. If you're not going to support comparing two different types of animal, then `Animal` should not be `Comparable<Animal>`; `Cat` should be `Comparable<Cat>` and `Dog` should be `Comparable<Dog>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`interface Animal` shouldn't be implementing `Comparable<Animal>` in the first place if you don't want its subclasses to be mutually comparable.

There is a relevant quote from *Effective Java 2nd Ed*, in Item 8 "Consider implementing Comparable" (I copied much of the following from [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41760105/3788176)):

> One consequence of these three provisions [of the `compareTo` contract] is that the equality test imposed by
>   a compareTo method must obey the same restrictions imposed by the equals contract:
>   reflexivity, symmetry, and transitivity. Therefore the same caveat applies:
>   there is no way to extend an instantiable class with a new value component while
>   preserving the compareTo contract, unless you are willing to forgo the benefits of
>   object-oriented abstraction (Item 8).

So, what this says is that *provided your subclass doesn't have any more values than the superclass used to determine ordering*, implementing `Comparable<Supertype>` is reasonable.

The implication of this, in addition to the general requirements of the `Comparable`, is that `Comparable<Superclass>` should be implemented identically in `Superclass` and all subclasses.

Answer (score 2):

When you define `Ainimal` as:

```
interface Animal extends Comparable<Animal> {
}
```

you're saying that any `Animal` can be compared to another `Animal`.

If you only want to compare `Dog` to `Dog`, you should define it this way:

```
interface Animal {
}

class Dog implements Animal, Comparable<Dog> {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Dog o) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `comparable` interface only states some things how to work together with 'equals', for example, that `compateTo()` should return 0 if `equals`returns 0.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Comparable.html

So actually it depends.
If it makes sense to your program, you could cast to `Animal`:

```
int compareTo(Dog o)
{
    Animal other = (Animal) o;
    ...
}
```

So if you want to sort Animal for size or for the number of search results on Google by using `compareTo` this would be a valid implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends of whether you want to be able to compare a Cat and a Dog. Broadly speaking, there are different possibilities

1. Compare all Animal instances with an order *consistent with Equal*

   You could for example use different attributes of animals in a way that 2 different animals cannot have all attributes the same. If it makes sense you can use the class name as such an attribute to compare a Cat and a Dog having all other attributes identical
2. Compare all Animal instances with an order *non consistent with Equal*

   Just a slight variation of the above: two animal will *compare equal* if their attributes are identical, even if `equals` between them will return false. Beware, it may be dangerous (even if possible), according to the Javadoc for [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

   > It is strongly recommended (though not required) that natural orderings be consistent with equals. This is so because sorted sets (and sorted maps) without explicit comparators behave "strangely" when they are used with elements (or keys) whose natural ordering is inconsistent with equals. In particular, such a sorted set (or sorted map) violates the general contract for set (or map), which is defined in terms of the equals method.
3. Only compare Animal instances in one class (and of course its subclasses). In that case, the declaration of the interface should be changed to use generics:

   ```
   interface Animal<T> extends Comparable<T> {
   }
   ```

   and 2 classes

   ```
   class Dog implements Animal<Dog> {

   }
   ```

   and

   ```
   class Cat implements Animal<Cat> {

   }
   ```