# Enforce subclass Java type on parameter

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, parameters

Is there any way of enforcing the subclass type on a parameter at compilation time?

Something like `this` but not for instances - for classes?

I have the classes:

```
public abstract class Animal {

  public abstract void follow(Animal a); // <-- how to declare it?

}
```

but I would like a subclass to never use the `Animal` base class, but rather only itself (the deriving class) as parameter:

```
public class Fish extends Animal {

  @Override
  public void follow(Fish f) { // error here, since it expects Animal
    tagAlong(f);
  }

  private void tagAlong(Fish f) {
    // do something  
  }

}
```

I want a `Fish` to only use parameters of type `Fish`, not `Animal`, the same way another subclass `Parrot` would use only a `Parrot` parameter on the method `follow()`.

I would strongly prefer to enforce this at compilation time, but if nothing else is possible runtime is a (less desirable) option.

Comment: I think you should use generics mate

Comment: That's precisely what `<T extends Animal>` is for.

Comment: It seems that unfortunately Java doesn't provide a safe way of doing this. The subclass must explicitly state the parameter type as itself. A careless programmer could specify a different type when creating the subclass 'Fish extends Animal<Parrot>'. Java would compile it and run it, even if it doesn't make sense.

Comment: After much debate I decided NOT to implement the accepted solution. Doing so requires to change a massive amount of code: change all the subclasses in the tree (95 classes), and all references to any class on the tree from all other "client" classes (300+ classes). For example, every single "for" needed to be changed. Too much trouble for a basic benefit. Ideally this should be part of Java language itself, not a trick.

Comment: @TheImpaler just read your comment there - I think you're right: refactoring such a large amount of code just to add this doens't look like a great idea. Moreover a coding mistake (e.g. parametrizing `Fish` with `Duck`, etc.) would still defeat the purpose, while compiling just fine. I suspect there isn't a good solution to your issue unfortunately, given the context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a trick to this.

From a design perspective, it's ugly, but it'll work in your case.

First things first: note that there's nothing really wrong with parametrizing with `Animal`, and checking the type at runtime.

Here's how to enforce inheritance with same-type parameter as method's signature:

```
// made class generic
public abstract class Animal<T extends Animal<T>> {

    public abstract void follow(T a);

}

// parametrizes with own type
public class Fish extends Animal<Fish> {

    @Override
    public void follow(Fish a) {
        // compiles
    }

}
```

You could also declare a generic method `follow` instead, parametrized with `<T extends Animal>` (and just `T` in the signature), but you can't enforce `Fish` in the signature in the `Fish` class.

Comment: You can add `<T extends Animal>` for further type-checking

Comment: I think this question should be marked as a duplicate, rather then answering it yet again. A very good and complete answer for this can be found here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354740/is-there-a-way-to-refer-to-the-current-type-with-a-type-variable

Comment: `public abstract class Animal<T extends Animal<T>>` makes more sense.

Comment: @RannLifshitz I don't see the one you point at as duplicate... am I missing something?

Comment: This seems to work. The compiler is complaining about it. Adding `<?>`. I think it should be `Fish extends Animal<?>>`.

Comment: @HBo and davidxxx good point, edited.

Comment: @Mena : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354740/is-there-a-way-to-refer-to-the-current-type-with-a-type-variable - the first answer here is a full blown version of your answer.

Comment: @RannLifshitz hmm. I see your point. The good answers there are the same as mine (or rather mine is the same as those). However the *question* seems to differ enough, and there is no accepted answer... Not sure what to do.

Comment: @Mena : I know what I am going to do (+1 for your answer).

Comment: @RannLifshitz - "the first answer" is not a fixed thing. It depends on whether the answers are sorted by activity, date, or votes. Better to say "the answer by Paul Bellora" (if that's what you meant).

Comment: @RannLifshitz thanks :) looks like there's consensus on closing as dupe anyway.

Comment: It seems that unfortunately Java doesn't provide a safe way of doing this. The subclass must explicitly state the parameter type as itself. A careless programmer could specify a different type when creating the subclass 'Fish extends Animal<Parrot>'. Java would compile it and run it, even if it doesn't make sense.

Comment: The bound here is useless. This declaration doesn't really accomplish anything more than `public abstract class Animal<T>`does.