# Self-type - requiring a type within a type bound

Tags: java, generics

I am wondering if it is possible to restrain a method declared on an interface to require a type *within a type bound*. In effect, I'd like to offer a method for casting a type that is somewhat type-safe in the absense of being able to provide real type-safety.

As an example, consider a hierarchy with a base type `Base` which is inherited via an intermediate interface. Typically, one knows about a type being of interface `FirstInterface` but not what specific class is implementing it. I'd like a method that allows casting to either implementation of an interface without allowing to cast to other implementations of `Base` as demonstrated in the following example:

```
interface Base<TYPE extends Base<TYPE>> {
  default <CAST extends TYPE> CAST as(Class<? extends CAST> type) {
    if (type.isInstance(this)) {
      return type.cast(this);
    } else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
  }
}

interface FirstIface<TYPE extends FirstIface<TYPE>> extends Base<TYPE> { }
class FirstClassA implements FirstIface<FirstClassA> { }
class FirstClassB implements FirstIface<FirstClassB> { }

interface SecondIface<TYPE extends SecondIface<TYPE>> extends Base<TYPE> { }
class SecondClassA implements SecondIface<SecondClassA> { }
class SecondClassB implements SecondIface<SecondClassB> { }

interface ThirdIface<TYPE extends ThirdIface<TYPE>> extends FirstIface<TYPE>, SecondIface<TYPE> { }
class ThirdClassA implements ThirdIface<ThirdClassA> { }
class ThirdClassB implements ThirdIface<ThirdClassB> { }
```

I'd hope to being able to make the following code compile in Java:

```
FirstIface<?> i = new FirstClassA();
FirstClassA a = i.as(FirstClassA.class); // desired: compiles, now: compiler error
FirstClassB b = i.as(FirstClassB.class); // desired: runtime exception, now: compiler error
```

The same should work for the hierarchy of `ThirdIFace`, whereas the following code should render a compiler error:

```
SecondIface<?> i = new SecondClassA();
SecondClassA a = i.as(SecondClassA.class); // now and desired: compiler error
SecondClassB b = i.as(SecondClassB.class); // now and desired: compiler error
```

Is there any way to declare `Base.as` to withhold this requirement? The code is auto-generated, so it would also be possible to provide an override in the interfaces which are auto-generated (as are the classes). When overrides are used, a scenario of `SecondIface extends FirstIface`.

Comment: Which JDK version are you planning to use?

Comment: This needs to compile on Java 11+.

Comment: Maybe I'm blind, but I don't see the structural difference between the `FirstIface` and the `SecondIface` snippet that might render the second one illegal at compile-time while the first one isn't.

Comment: If you want to allow to cast only to `FirstIface`, but not other, why don't you declare it such by `default <CAST extends FirstIface>`? Or, as others point out, how else do you decide which is actually `FirstIface`, which you allow and which is `SecondIface`, which you forbid.

Comment: I want to allow providing any class as an argument that actually implements `FirstIface`, which are `FirstClassA` and `FirstClassB`. I want to forbid classes that do not implement `FirstIface` such as `SecondClassA` and `SecondClassB`. But since the wildcard could be any subtype of `FirstIface`, it does not allow for any subtype of `FirstIFace`. I'd like to permit any subtype of `IFirstIface` but not any other type.

Comment: So, do you want `FirstIface` to be "hardcoded" into the `as()` method, such that it only compiles with `FirstIface`-implementing classes, and not with others?

Comment: I think I got it now: you want the `as()` method to place two restrictions on its argument. A `Base<X>` should only accept types that are both subclasses of `X` and implementations of `FirstIface`. Is that your problem?

Comment: Yes, they should be subclasses of the raw interface, in a way.

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7355094

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to only allow calls that are likely to succeed, with likely to succeed meaning that we know (statically) that `SUB` is a subtype of `SUPER` when attempting to cast an instance of type `SUPER` to type `SUB`, I'm not sure that is possible.

A problem, even after overcoming the issue of not having a type variable for, let's say, the intermediate self type (`FirstIface<?>` in your example), is that the compiler will infer `SUPER==Object` (or `SUPER==Base<?>`) if necessary to satisfy `SUB extends SUPER`.

> The code is auto-generated, so it would also be possible to provide an override in the interfaces which are auto-generated

I don't think that would help. The goal would be for methods in sub-interfaces to have more restrictive parameter types than what is declared in the supertype, but parameter types are not covariant (covariant parameter types would violate the Liskov substitution principle)

> But since the wildcard could be any subtype of FirstIface, it does not allow for any subtype of FirstIFace

Yeah. We only have 1) the self type variable `TYPE` which is for the final implementing type, and 2) a type for the `Base` interface. We don't have a way to write down the type for the intermediate type information that is known at the call site.

I suspect the closest approximation to your goal would be to:

1. Use a static method for the cast, and
2. Avoid use of type inference at the call site, since javac will happily infer `Object` for the supertype to make the code compile.

Of course, this isn't a good solution, since avoiding type inference is impractical. Here is a full example:

```java
public class Hello {
    interface Base<TYPE extends Base<TYPE>> {}

    interface FirstIface<TYPE extends FirstIface<TYPE>> extends Base<TYPE> {}

    static final class FirstClassA implements FirstIface<FirstClassA> { }
    static final class FirstClassB implements FirstIface<FirstClassB> { }

    interface SecondIface<TYPE extends SecondIface<TYPE>> extends Base<TYPE> { }

    static final class SecondClassA implements SecondIface<SecondClassA> { }
    static final class SecondClassB implements SecondIface<SecondClassB> { }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FirstIface<?> i = new FirstClassA();

        FirstClassA a = Hello.<FirstIface<?>, FirstClassA>as(i, FirstClassA.class); // works
        FirstClassB b = Hello.<FirstIface<?>, FirstClassB>as(i, FirstClassB.class); // runtime error

        SecondClassA c = Hello.<FirstIface<?>, SecondClassA>as(i, SecondClassA.class); // compile error
        SecondClassB d = Hello.<FirstIface<?>, SecondClassB>as(i, SecondClassB.class); // compile error
    }

    static <SUPER, SUB extends SUPER> SUB as(SUPER obj, Class<? extends SUB> c) {
        return (SUB) obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is elegant, but it defeats the convenience I am aiming for. I'd like to make the compiler help out in a large, autogenerated type hierarchy. If you'd need to explicitly define the arguments every time, I doubt people would use it.

Comment: Right, but the key point is that what you are trying to do requires covariant method parameter types (parameter types that are *more* restrictive in subtypes), and that is unsound and not possible in Java. If covariant parameter types were allowed, you would be able to write totally type-safe looking code that crashes with a type error at runtime.

Comment: I was afraid so, but it would not be the first time that some mindtrick can accomplish this, especially now that the code already is generated. My impression was however also that it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I could come up with is:

```java
    interface Base<TYPE extends Base<TYPE, BASE>, BASE extends Base<?, ?>> {

        default <CAST extends BASE> CAST as(Class<CAST> type) {
            if (type.isInstance(this)) {
                return type.cast(this);
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
        }
    }

    interface FirstIface<TYPE extends FirstIface<TYPE>> extends Base<TYPE, FirstIface<?>> {}
    static class FirstClassA implements FirstIface<FirstClassA> {}
    static class FirstClassB implements FirstIface<FirstClassB> {}

    interface SecondIface<TYPE extends SecondIface<TYPE>> extends Base<TYPE, SecondIface<?>> {}
    static class SecondClassA implements SecondIface<SecondClassA> {}
    static class SecondClassB implements SecondIface<SecondClassB> {}

    public static void main(String... args) {
        {
            FirstIface<?> i = new FirstClassA();
            FirstClassA a = i.as(FirstClassA.class);
            FirstClassB b = i.as(FirstClassB.class); // runtime exception
            SecondClassA x = i.as(SecondClassA.class); // compile exception
            SecondClassB y = i.as(SecondClassB.class); // compile exception
        }
        {
            SecondIface<?> i = new SecondClassA();
            FirstClassA a = i.as(FirstClassA.class); // compile exception
            FirstClassB b = i.as(FirstClassB.class); // compile exception
            SecondClassA x = i.as(SecondClassA.class);
            SecondClassB y = i.as(SecondClassB.class); // runtime exception
        }
        new FirstClassA().as(FirstClassB.class); // unfortunately, this compiles fine :-(
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this makes it impossible to create hierarchies. I added this scenario to my question by `ThirdIface`, other then that, this is an elegant approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the `FirstIface` when generating the `Base` interface without all the generics madness:

```
interface Base {
    default <CAST extends FirstIface> CAST as(Class<CAST> type) {
        if (type.isInstance(this)) {
            return type.cast(this);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
}

interface FirstIface extends Base { }
class FirstClassA implements FirstIface { }
class FirstClassB implements FirstIface { }

interface SecondIface extends Base { }
class SecondClassA implements SecondIface { }
class SecondClassB implements SecondIface { }

public class Generics {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FirstIface i = new FirstClassA();
        FirstClassA a = i.as(FirstClassA.class);
        FirstClassB b = i.as(FirstClassB.class); // runtime exception

        SecondIface j = new SecondClassA();
        SecondClassA c = j.as(SecondClassA.class); // compiler error
        SecondClassB d = j.as(SecondClassB.class); // compiler error
    }
}
```

Comment: Not quite what I had in mind, this should work for any hirarchy of which there may be plenty per interface.

Comment: Per what interface? The `Base` interface? Or the first interface (the one allowed to compile)? It's not entirely clear to me what you want to achieve exactly and how you would like to mark the allowed/forbidden types.

Comment: The `Base.as` method should also work for `SecondIface`, for example.